# Insert values from dynamic table into database

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to get the values of a dynamically generated table and insert them into a database.
This is what i have right now:

JS: Note all values work, they get added to the table just fine. This function gets called when a button (not on the HTML code) its pressed.

```js
function addRow1( price ) {
  var dish = document.getElementById( "cmbDish" );
  var amount = document.getElementById( "txtAmount" ).value;
  if(amount == "" || amount == "0"){
   amount = "1";
  }
  var table = document.getElementById( "datatable" );
  var comments = document.getElementById( 'txtComments' );
  var subt = amount * price;

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow( rowCount );
  

  row.insertCell( 0 ).innerHTML = '<input name="fdish[]" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; text-align:center; width:100%" disabled value=' + dish.value + '>';
  row.insertCell( 1 ).innerHTML = '<input name="fcomment[]" style="border:solid; background-color:transparent; text-align:center; width:100%" value=' + comments.value + '>';
  row.insertCell( 2 ).innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="famount[]" style="border:solid; background-color:transparent; text-align:center; width:100%" value=' + amount + '>';
  row.insertCell( 3 ).innerHTML = '<input name="fprice[]" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; text-align:center; width:100%" disabled value= $' + price + '>';
  row.insertCell( 4 ).innerHTML = '<input name="fsubtotal[]" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; text-align:center; width:100%" disabled value= $' + subt + '>';
  row.insertCell( 5 ).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow1(this)">';
  

 }
```

HTML / PHP: Note the button on the end its the one that makes the POST

```
<form id="frmOrder" name="frmOrder" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>#Order" >

<div id="data">
<h2>List:</h2>
<table id="datatable"  border="1" cellpadding="2" width="977">
    <tr>
        <td width="193"><h4 align="center">Dish</h4></td>
        <td width="300"><h4 align="center">Comments</h4></td>
        <td width="117"><h4 align="center">Amount</h4></td>
        <td width="100"><h4 align="center">Price</h4></td>
        <td width="119"><h4 align="center">SubTotal</h4></td>
        <td width="140"><h4 align="center">Actions</h4></td>
    </tr>
</table>
&nbsp;<br/>
</div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <p align="center"><input type="submit" class="button special" id="btnplaceOrder" name="btnplaceOrder" value="Place Order" /></p>
        </ul>
</form>
```

How can i get all the values from the table and insert them into a database table. I have the database already created with all the fields

I've tried this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['btnplaceOrder'])&&$_POST["btnplaceOrder"]!=""){

    foreach($_POST['fdish'] as $key => $value){
        $dish = $_POST["fdish"][$key];
        $comment = $_POST["fcomment"][$key];
        $amount = $_POST["famount"][$key];
        $price = $_POST["fprice"][$key];

        $res = $object->do_query("INSERT into table(Id_order, Id_menu, amount, price, comment) values (1', '$dish', '$amount', '$price', '$comment')");

    }     

}
```

But didn't work, got no errors so i don't know whats wrong with it

Comment: Looks like non of your `<input>` fields have got a `name=""` attribute. Without that they will not get sent to the PHP by the browser

Comment: yea i tried put them name like this `name=item1[]` and run a `foreach` to get the values of the array but it didn't seem to work for me, don't know why

Comment: `row.insertCell( 0 ).innerHTML = '<input name="item1[]" ........`

Comment: Yea sorry, i updated the js with the names, my problem is that i dont know how to get the values and make a SQL query to insert them into a table

Comment: Javascript runs on the client side while Mysql, Postgress etc runs on the server side. You probably may need a server-side language to work on the queries to connect Javascript and your database. So, you are working with PHP already, that is a server-side language.

Comment: I will assume that you are working with Mysql and PHP, so give a try with AJAX? https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: I used AJAX to get some info(the price) from the database table but i don't know how to use AJAX to get the values from the HTML table and then insert all the data into the database

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
I change the attribute `disabled` to `readOnly`. I forgot that `disabled` attribute block the POST and send nothing